# Choose between ids that only meet some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm facing a problem with my project. My user can create a new div by clicking a button, but he can remove whatever div he wants, expect the first one. So if he create 2 new divs here is what the code will look like:

```
<div id="container1">
<input type="text" id="title1"><br />
<input type="text" id="description1">
</div>
<div id="container2">
<input type="text" id="title2"><br />
<input type="text" id="description2">
</div>
<div id="container3">
<input type="text" id="title3"><br />
<input type="text" id="description3">
</div>
```

If the user remove the second div my code will look like this.

```
<div id="container1">
<input type="text" id="title1"><br />
<input type="text" id="description1">
</div>
<div id="container3">
<input type="text" id="title3"><br />
<input type="text" id="description3">
</div>
```

Pretty simple. Now I want to use the information entered by the user in the text inputs, but I don't know how to select the active divs. Is there a way to select the container1 and container3 in the example above?
Keep in mind that the user can use up to 99 new div.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: You HTML is invalid.  [The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: I've updated my example code. It's not my actual code and typed it for the sake of example. Thank you,

Comment: You're question isn't clear.  `I don't know how to select the active divs`, div's can't be active so I don't know what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to each item. You would need to amend your code that is called when the button is clicked to handle this.

Let's say you gave all titles a class of "myTitle" and you gave all descriptions a class of "myDescription". Your div created would look something like this:

```
<div id="container1">
  <input type="text" id="title" class="myTitle"> 
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="description" class="myDescription">
</div>
```

Now, in order to get all titles and descriptions you'd use jQuery and say:

```
$('.myTitle').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});

$('.myDescription').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The problem with this methods is that I already have my class taken class="inputs" that is applied to all my textfields, so I can't use a class.

Comment: @CreekBarbara You can add many classes, you just need to add a space between them. For example: <input type="text" id="title" class="myTitle inputs">

Comment: I'm trying to test this on fiddle but doesn't seem to work. https://jsfiddle.net/m6Luv5do/3/

Comment: @CreekBarbara That's just an issue with jsfiddle. Here it is in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/viyuxez/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

Just apply a CSS selector:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="container1">
        <input type="text" id="title"><br />
        <input type="text" id="description">
    </div>
    <div id="container3">
        <input type="text" id="title1"><br />
        <input type="text" id="description1">
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('#parent > div')`

See here for more information: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: I'm trying to make a Fiddle but I'm not sure how to use this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have multiple divs with the id "title" and "description", so change those to class. You can select the `nth` div with jquery: `$("#container" + n)`

you can select the title of the `nth` div: `$("#container" + n).children(".title");

you can select all of the divs by adding a class to them, such as `.container`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my code. The problem is that I don't know how many div I have, and after that I've to select the ones that are active by there id.